# How to disable the typo in comment by resharper

Tags: resharper

For Resharper can't support Chinese well that all of my comment will be suggest changed.

[image]

But I don't think I need to do it.

Questions 1: how to disable the typo in the comment by Resharper?

Questions 2: where can I find the Chinese dictionary? I find [wooorm/dictionaries](https://github.com/wooorm/dictionaries/tree/master/dictionaries) but I can't find the Chinese dictionary.

Answer (score 29):

Resharper 2018.2.1 bring the ReSpeller that just like with code analysis, ReSpeller scans for spelling mistakes and typos in identifiers, comments, string literals and more, and provides quick-fixes to resolve the problem.

To disable the typo in the comment by Resharper, you should click the Resharper and enter option.

You should select the `Code Inspection->inspection severity` and then you should type `typo` to search see this image.

[image]

You can toggle the `Typo in comment` to open or close it.

And the other way is to disable ReSpeller.

You should select `ReSpeller` and then you should uncheck it.

[image]

See [Spell Checking with ReSpeller](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Spell_Checking.html)

[Integrated spell checking with ReSpeller in ReSharper and Rider](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/07/10/integrated-spell-checking-respeller-resharper-rider/)

[hunspell/hunspell: The most popular spellchecking library.](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell)

Answer (score 5):

Disable the typo by ReSharper

- ReSharper → Options
- Code Inspection → Inspection Severity
- Search: `Typo`
- `Disable` whatever you want

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable those once per class/interface, you can use the `SuppressMessage` Attribute (where `CommentTypo` is the inspection you asked for) like so:

```cs
    [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "InconsistentNaming")]
    [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "IdentifierTypo")]
    [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "CommentTypo")]
    public interface IHaveNoControlOverTheirApi
    {
        //...
    }
```

You can also [suppress code inspections in other scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#suppress) if you like.

Have a look at [ReSharper's documentation on code inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Inspections_CSHARP.html#Spelling) to see what kinds of inspections can be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

#### For your question 1:

Maybe what you need is to turn off non-English spell checking only, not turn off all the comments spell checking. Unfortunately, ReSharper doesn't provide such an option to turn off only non-English spell checking.

I've reported this issue to its official document and you can see the discussions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Spell_Checking.html

ReSharper has an issue to trace this problem: [ReSpeller: Ignore Chinese and Japanese: RSPL-6949](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSPL-6949). So you can just wait for this improvement in the next bugfix.

#### For your question 2:

I can't find any Chinese dictionaries for spell checking.

Answer (score 1):

The setting is under Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> ReSpeller reference the article below.
https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000537679-Turn-off-Spellcheck-in-ReSharper-VS-2017